# Canvas.move not working in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am doing this basic game for an assignment, at its core involving moving a circle around a canvas with the arrow keys. For reasons I can't seem to pinpoint, the circle won't move and it seems to not even be calling the move function. I looked around and found some people that were having similar problems but I tried the fixes for theirs to no avail. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    from tkinter import *
    class CircleGame(Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    Frame.__init__(self)
    self.master.title("Circle Game")
    self.grid()

    self.canvas = Canvas(self, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "white")
    self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    self.canvas.create_oval(100,100,200,200,tags = "circle")
    self.x = 150
    self.y = 150

    self.canvas.bind("<Up>", self.moveCircle)
    self.canvas.bind("<Down>", self.moveCircle)
    self.canvas.bind("<Left>", self.moveCircle)
    self.canvas.bind("<Right>", self.moveCircle)


  def moveCircle(self, event):
    if event.keysym == "Up":
        self.canvas.move("circle", 0, -5)
        self.y -= 5

    elif event.keysym == "Down":
        self.canvas.move("circle", 0, 5)
        self.y +=5

    elif event.keysym == "Left":
        self.canvas.move("circle", -5, 0)
        self.x -=5    

    elif event.keysym == "Right":
        self.canvas.move("circle", 5, 0)
        self.x +=5      
    self.canvas.update()


def main():
    CircleGame().mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Tags are for a reason :)

Comment: Also, you didn't post any code that actually runs.  It's all just class and function definitions.

Comment: @John Not sure what you mean by "tags are for a reason." if that's in reference to tagging the post I fail to see what i did wrong in that regard, if it  is in reference to the code, I tagged the oval as "circle" and used "circle" in the canvas.move() so elaboration would be appreciated a bit more than vague comments and downvotes

Comment: I was referring to adding "python: " to the start of your question title.  I assumed leaving that comment at the exact same time I removed that would be non-vague enough.  It's generally frowned upon to put tags in question titles.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so simple problem, I hadnt added a self.canvas.focus() so the window wasnt receiving my inputs